# I've created a WCF service and now I want to call it from a reference but why InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I've written a WCF service. I have successfully browsed to the service and it says:

```
You have created a service.
```

So then I add a reference to it using a the 'Add Service Reference' in visual studio. Then I write the following code to consume it....

```
ServiceReference1.VLSContentServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.VLSContentServiceClient("VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour");
List<ServiceReference1.Category> cats = client.GetCategoriesByGET();
```

But im getting the error:

> Could not find endpoint element with
>   name
>   'VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour'
>   and contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IVLSContentService'
>   in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because
>   no endpoint element matching this name
>   could be found in the client element.

It makes no sense because the argument 'endPointConfigurationName' matches what I have set it to in the service. Here is the service configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceBehaviour" name="VLSContentService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IVLSContentService"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VLSContentServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Whats going on?

Comment: your endpoint address is empty?  How is it supposed to find the endpoint?

Comment: Check your client config..or try re adding the service reference, might be you added some changes due to that client and server config are miss matching..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using **REST** service - client for such service cannot be created with Add service reference. That is only for SOAP services (no webHttpBinding and webHttp behavior). Also once you use SOAP service you don't pass name of any server side feature to the constructor of the proxy. The proxy constructor expects name of client endpoint from client's configuration.

[How to consume REST service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/04/21/how-to-consume-rest-services-with-wcf.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your contract is not correct.  you have:

```
contract="IVLSContentService"/>
```

and it is expecting:

```
contract="ServiceReference1.IVLSContentService"/>
```

according to the error message.

also your endpoint address is empty.  Does that not need to contain something?

Answer (score 0):

The VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour parameter while creating an instance of client is the Name of the endpoint and not the endpoing behaviour.

Change

```
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IVLSContentService"/>
```

to

```
    <endpoint address="" name ="Client" behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IVLSContentService"/>
```

and create a service client as

ServiceReference1.VLSContentServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.VLSContentServiceClient("Client");

Also your address is missing which is bit strange.

Comment: The endpoint address is empty when you add a local service reference, such as one within your own solution.